# Summarise unique combinations in data frame

Tags: r

In the example dataset below I need to find the number of unique customers per product summarised per year. The output has to be a data.frame with the headers: **year - product - number of customers**

Thanks for your help.

```
year <- c("2009", "2010")
product <- c("a", "b", "c")
df <- data.frame(customer = sample(letters, 50, replace = T),
                 product = sample(product, 50, replace = T),
                 year = sample(year, 50, replace = T))
```

Comment: I'm not down-voting this one. But, a question that shows no research effort is very likely to be *down-voted*. If possible edit your question to show us what you've managed so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `aggregate()` (in the included-with-R stats package):

```
agdf<-aggregate(customer~product+year,df,function(x)length(unique(x)))
agdf
#  product year customer
#1       a 2009        7
#2       b 2009        8
#3       c 2009       10
#4       a 2010        7
#5       b 2010        7
#6       c 2010        6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `plyr`'s `summarise`:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(product, year), summarise, customers=length(unique(customer)))
```